# Details in proving that the image of a dense subset of a domain is itself dense in the range

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology, continuity

> Let $f:X\rightarrow Y$ be a continuous function,and let $E$ be a dense subset of $X$.
>
> Prove that $f(E)$ is dense in $f(X)$.

I know the solution, but a few details are unclear to me:

We proceed by proving that every open subset of $f(X)$ intersects $f(E)$. Let $V$ be an open subset of $f(X)$. There exists $V'$ open in Y, such that $V' \cap f(X)  =V$ **(How do we know that there exists an open V' in Y, and how do we know that it satisfies $\boldsymbol{V' \cap f(X)  =V}$?)**. Since $f$ is continuous, $f^{-1}(V')$ is  open in $X$. Then $f^{-1}(V') \cap E \neq \emptyset$ because $E$ is dense in $X$. This implies that $f(f^{-1}(V')) \cap f(E) \neq \emptyset$. But $f(f^{-1}(V'))\subset V'$, and so $\boldsymbol{V \cap f(E) =V' \cap f(E)}\neq \emptyset$; QED. **(How did we arrive at the bolded inequality?)**

Comment: You seem to not understand a lot of things. Obviously there is some open set $V'$ in $Y$. For example, $Y$ is open in $Y$. However, it's not the case that any open $V'$ in $Y$ intersects $f(X)$ precisely at $V$. The proof is saying that there exists some open set $V'$ *such that* $V' \cap f(X) = V$.

Comment: @mathworker21 Okay, I think I follow that part (I seem to get bogged down in definitions and lose sight of obvious concepts!). Could you please explain to me how we arrive at the final equality?

Comment: it seems like you need to get better at some preliminaries before doing topology

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first bolded statement is just the definition of subspace topology: if you have a topological space $A$ and a subset $B \subset A$ then according to the said topology a subset $V \subset B$ is open if and only if there is an open subset $U$ of $A$ such that $V= B \cap U$. Thus being $V \subset f(X)$ open there must be an open subset $V'$ of $Y$ such that $V= V' \cap f(X)$.

The bolded equality at the end is just a basic conclusion of set inclusions: being $f(E)$ a subset of $f(X)$ we get $V' \cap f(E)= V' \cap f(E) \cap f(X)$, but now $V' \cap f(X)= V$ and we obtain $V' \cap f(E)= V' \cap f(X) \cap f(E)=V \cap f(E)$.